# Suggest a logic or an algorithm for this puzzle

Tags: c#, algorithm, logic

There are two arrays

```
Array1 {5,6,7,8}
```

and

```
Array2 {2,1,1,0}
```

Here is a pattern which satisfies a certain condition

```
8,6,5,7
```

**The Condition:** Considering the pattern above Array2's respective element to Array1's 8 says that it has 0 elements greater than 8 to its left in the pattern,similarly Array2's respective element to Array1's 6 says that it has 1 element greater than 6 to the left of it in the pattern.And so on......

Given the 2 arrays is there a way to generate the pattern.Any algorithm logic would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think I understand "the condition"... but if you're able to describe your project with what each element of the array means, you can probably write the "algorithm" my computing each element one by one using simple logic / arithmetic?

Comment: @ChrisMoutray no dat wont be correct since 6 has only one element greater than itself to the left of it.if the pattern is 8,6,5,7 it has 2 elements greater than it to the left

Answer (score 3):

Here's an algorithm that should work:

- Sort the numbers. (**Edit**: by number **and then by left-count**)
- For each number, given it needs `n` larger numbers to its left, put it in the `n+1`th free slot from the left.
- If there aren't that many free slots left, the two original arrays don't allow such a pattern to exist.

Here's how it works on your example:

- Start with the smallest number, 5. It needs two larger items on its left. Since *all* the other items are larger, put it third from the left. `_ _ 5 _`
- Next smallest is 6. It needs one larger item on the left. Since *all* remaining items are larger, it needs to go in the second free slot. `_ 6 5 _`
- Next smallest is 7. It needs one larger item on the left. Since *all* remaining items are larger, it needs to go in the second free slot. `_ 6 5 7`
- Next is 8. It needs no larger items on the left. It needs to go in the first free slot. `8 6 5 7`

Here's a rough implementation in C#:

```
public static int[] algorithm(int[] numbers, int[] counts)
{
    var pairs = numbers                         // EDIT:
        .Zip(counts, (n, c) => new { n, c })    // This is needed to
        .OrderBy(p => p.n)                      // correctly handle
        .ThenBy(p => p.c)                       // duplicate numbers
        .ToArray();
    int[] output = new int[pairs.Length];
    List<int> freeIndices = Enumerable.Range(0, pairs.Length).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < pairs.Length; i++)
    {
        if (pairs[i].c < freeIndices.Count)
        {
            int outputIndex = freeIndices[pairs[i].c];
            freeIndices.RemoveAt(pairs[i].c);
            output[outputIndex] = pairs[i].n;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

**Edit**: My original code didn't correctly handle duplicate numbers; this version now should do so.

Comment: What if the two arrays were: {1,2,2,4}{0,1,0,0}?  Your output would be {1,2,2,4}

Comment: @BuhBuh You're right, this messes up if two of the items are the same. Thinking cap back on.

Comment: @BuhBuh This should work now; thanks for pointing it out. This is possibly now equivalent to your answer, just doing things in a slightly different order.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than thinking of this as two arrays, instead I would like to think of it as a single list of Number/LeftCount pairs.

First consider only the set of pairs where (LeftCount == 0).  Of this set select the one with the lowest Number (`n`).

Write `n` to the screen.

Remove this pair from the list.

For all remaining pairs with Number less than `n`, decrement LeftCount.

Repeat until there there are no pairs left in your list.

If you understand the idea of this algorithm it would not be too hard to code it up as two separate arrays.

Comment: wat do in case 2 numbers have same count

Comment: If two pairs both have a LeftCount of zero then select the one with the lowest Number.  If the Numbers are also equal, then do select either.

Comment: might be a trivial doubt but y select the one with lowest number

Comment: Suppose your arrays where {1,2} {0,0}.  The 2 cannot be to the left of the 1.  So should select the 1 first and then the 2.  Or, more generally, select lower numbers first, so that they end up on the left.